# Color picker from a sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, slider

Hello I am trying to select a color using a slider with a sprite like this

[image]

The sprites will be the presets for the colors, and I cant mathematically generate the sprite.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to get the texture from the click position and get the pixel color of the hit position:

```
Vector2 pos = Input.mousePosition; 
Camera cam = Camera.mainCamera; 
Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(pos);
Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, ray.direction, out hitPoint, 10000.0f);
Color mycolor;
if(hitPoint.collider) {
    Texture2D tex = (Texture2D) hitPoint.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.mainTexture; 
    mycolor = tex.GetPixelBilinear(hitPoint.textureCoord2.x, hitPoint.textureCoord2.y); 
}
```